# mobile jquery datepicker with only date and month

Tags: jquery-mobile

I want a jquery mobile Datepicker that will allw only date and month selection not year
I am using the below plugin given on link
Visit http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0a4.1/experiments/ui-datepicker/ 
can anybody help me out to format it accoring to my need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use DateBox ( http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/ ) which has many options for customization.  To setup a month and day only picker, you can use either the 'datebox' or 'flipbox' modes:

```
<input name="Date1" id="Date1" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode":"datebox", "overrideHeaderFormat": "%B - %d", "overrideDateFormat": "%B - %d", "overrideDateFieldOrder": ["m", "d"]}'}'' /> 

<input name="Date2" id="Date2" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode":"flipbox", "overrideHeaderFormat": "%B - %d", "overrideDateFormat": "%B - %d", "overrideDateFieldOrder": ["m", "d"]}'}'' />
```

You use the override formats to present month and day. %b is the 3 letter abbreviation for month, %B is full month name. If you prefer a number, use %m.

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/Xv5wz/2/)**

For more info on DateBox, see the many Demos at the site